# How to factorise algebraic quotients?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, rational-functions

I am trying to simplify an algebraic expression of the following:

$\frac{2f+g-h}{10f^2+3gf-fh-g^2+3gh-2h^2}$

the answer is apparently:

$\frac{1}{5f-g+2h}$

but I can't seem to get to that at all? Could someone give me an explanation as to how this is achieved?

Comment: Have you tried to see if you could simplify the denominator into $(2f+g-h)\times(af+bg+ch)$ for some real numbers $a,b,c$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quadratic form (dimension three) factors (possibly with complex coefficents) if and only if its Hessian matrix has determinant zero. You have
$$  10 f^2 - g^2 - 2 h^2 + 3gh-hf+3fg  $$
for
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
20 & 3& -1\\
3 & -2 & 3 \\
-1 & 3 & -4
\end{array}
\right)
$$

of determinant $0.$

One way to factor the form is to find a matrix congruence with a diagonal form, 
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 3 }{ 20 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 20 }  &  -  \frac{ 9 }{ 7 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
20 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 49 }{ 20 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 20 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 20 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 9 }{ 7 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
20 & 3 &  - 1 \\ 
3 &  - 2 & 3 \\ 
 - 1 & 3 &  - 4 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

This says that double the original form is 
$$ 20 \left( f+\frac{3g}{20} - \frac{h}{20}\right)^2 - \frac{49}{20} \left( g - \frac{9h}{7}\right)^2  $$
or
$$ \frac{1}{20} \left( 20f+3g - h\right)^2 - \frac{1}{20} \left( 7g -9h     \right)^2  $$
or
$$ \frac{1}{20} (20f+3g-h+7g-9h)(20f+3g-h-7g+9h) $$
$$ \frac{1}{20} (20f+10g-10h)(20f-4g+8h) $$
$$ 2 (2f+g-h)(5f-g+2h) $$

=======================================================================

Algorithm discussed at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia
$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
20 & 3 &  - 1 \\ 
3 &  - 2 & 3 \\ 
 - 1 & 3 &  - 4 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  D_0 = H  $$
$$ E_j^T D_{j-1} E_j = D_j  $$
$$  P_{j-1} E_j = P_j  $$
$$ E_j^{-1} Q_{j-1}  = Q_j  $$
$$  P_j Q_j = Q_j P_j = I  $$
$$ P_j^T H P_j = D_j  $$
$$ Q_j^T D_j Q_j = H  $$

$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
20 & 3 &  - 1 \\ 
3 &  - 2 & 3 \\ 
 - 1 & 3 &  - 4 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 20 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 20 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 20 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
20 & 0 &  - 1 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 49 }{ 20 }  &  \frac{ 63 }{ 20 }  \\ 
 - 1 &  \frac{ 63 }{ 20 }  &  - 4 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 20 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 20 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 20 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 20 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 20 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
20 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 49 }{ 20 }  &  \frac{ 63 }{ 20 }  \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 63 }{ 20 }  &  -  \frac{ 81 }{ 20 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 9 }{ 7 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 20 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 7 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 9 }{ 7 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 20 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 20 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 9 }{ 7 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
20 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 49 }{ 20 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 3 }{ 20 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 7 }  &  \frac{ 9 }{ 7 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
20 & 3 &  - 1 \\ 
3 &  - 2 & 3 \\ 
 - 1 & 3 &  - 4 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 20 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 7 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 9 }{ 7 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
20 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 49 }{ 20 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 3 }{ 20 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 20 }  &  -  \frac{ 9 }{ 7 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
20 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 49 }{ 20 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 20 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 20 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 9 }{ 7 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
20 & 3 &  - 1 \\ 
3 &  - 2 & 3 \\ 
 - 1 & 3 &  - 4 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Comment: Interesting. Wikipedia’s article on quadratic forms doesn’t mention anything about factoring or Hessian matrices. I see your algorithm, but do you have any accessible links to info on the connection with Hessian matrices and quadratic forms?

Comment: @T.M. link to an article https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.123.4.347?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: Thanks. I don’t have direct access to that but I’ll see what I can do.

Comment: @T.M. as far as quadratic forms, you probably don't need it. In any dimension, if you can solve $P^T D P = H$ where $D$ and Hessian $H$ are of rank $2,$ that lets you factor the quadratic form as I did above. With less pleasant coefficents and linear forms $L_1$ and $L_2,$ the expression $a L_1^2 + b L_2^2$ may involve irrational numbers, then if $ab > 0$ may involve complex numbers. For example, semidefinite $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - yz-zx-xy$ needs the nontrivial cube roots of $3$ to factor, that is $\omega^2 + \omega + 1 = 0$

Comment: ok where I’m stuck is in the interpretation of $$Q^T DQ=H$$ says that double the original form is…

Comment: @T.M. No, that calculation gives something new... It is built in (Taylor's series multivariable) that for a column vector $V = (x,y,z)^T \; , \;$ the value of the quadratic form at $V$ is $(1/2) V^T H V \; , \;$ where $H$ is the Hessian matrix of second partial derivatives of the form $f(x,y,z)$.   Also, most of this does not depend on the precise dimension 3.

Comment: Sorry I wasn’t clear, I mean how to get the $a L_1^2 + b L_2^2$ from the previous.

Comment: @T.M.  then $a= d_{11}$ and $L_1 = q_{11} x + q_{12} y + q_{13}z, $ after which  $b= d_{22}$ and $L_2 = q_{21} x + q_{22} y + q_{23}z \; . \; $  In the question he used $f,g,h$ rather than $x,y,z$

Answer (score 2):

A priori, it is not clear whether that expression can be simplified. At first glance, you have two options, because the numerator is a polynomial of homogeneous degree $1$: either the numerator divides the denominator, or it doesn't.

Suppose the first option is true, that numerator divides denominator. Then because the denominator is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $2$, there exists a homogeneous polynomial $p(f,g,h) = a \cdot f + b \cdot g + c \cdot h$ such that
$$\text{numerator} \times p(f,g,h) = \text{denominator}.$$
Expanding the above equation and equating coefficients on both sides gives a system of equations in $a,b,c$ which may have a solution (in which case the fraction can indeed be simplified), or may not have a solution (in which case the fraction is in simplest form).

Answer (score 1):

Since you know it does simplify to that you know that the numerator divides the denominator. You could use multivariable polynomial long division to find the result.

I should also mention that your problem looks kind of reasonable that it would simplify since $5f$ times the first term gives the first term of the product and $2h$ times the last works also. Then it’s just a question of finding if there is a coefficient for $g$ that works. You could try $5f+ag+2h$ times your numerator and see if you could equate coefficients to find a.

Where did this come up by the way?